# valores nulos en mysql

Tags: php, mysql

tengo una tabla mes, una tabla despacho y otra tabla detalle_despacho, lo que necesito es poder sacar el total de productos vendidos de cada mes pero con eso necesito que si en tal mes no hay registrado ningún despacho que aún así me muestre el mes diciendo que el total de productos vendidos fue de 0, esta es la consulta que tengo:

```
SELECT SUM(dd.dd_cantidad) cantidad, desp.des_numero numero, m_nombre
FROM detalle_despacho dd JOIN despacho desp ON dd.despacho_des_numero = desp.des_numero JOIN mes m ON MONTH(desp.des_fecha) = m_id 
WHERE YEAR(desp.des_fecha) = 2018 AND dd.producto_pr_id = 1000 GROUP BY MONTH(desp.des_fecha)
```

el año es solo un ejemplo pero si selecciono 2018 necesito ver de enero a diciembre y que aquellos meses sin despachos solo me muestre 0, espero su ayuda, gracias!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
   SUM(ifnull(dd.dd_cantidad, 0)) cantidad, desp.des_numero numero, m_nombre 
FROM 
   detalle_despacho dd 
JOIN despacho desp ON dd.despacho_des_numero = desp.des_numero
RIGHT  JOIN mes m ON MONTH(desp.des_fecha) = m_id 
WHERE 
   YEAR(desp.des_fecha) = 2018 
AND dd.producto_pr_id = 1000 
GROUP BY 
  MONTH(desp.des_fecha)
```

Tienes que usar  `right join` con la tabla meses, así se muestran todos los registros de la tabla meses aunque no tengan un detalle, en este caso la cantidad será NULL, la función `IFNULL()` se usa para establecer en 0 el valor de la columna cantidad cuando esta sea NULL.

Comment: lo ideal en este foro es explicación mas código, así como lo pones la respuesta es de muy baja calidad

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, pero aún sigue sin mostrarme todos los meses, seguiré intentando

Comment: Puedes poner la estructura de tus tablas para revisar la consulta con más exactitud.